# Notation package: parenthesis placement for SuperscriptBox

Tags: custom-notation, precedence

The question concerns the `Notation` package.
I want to define notation for the function very similar to the built-in `Power[a,b]` function.
I am trying to do it in  the following way:

```
Needs["Notation`"];
Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[SuperscriptBox["A_","B_"]]  \[DoubleLongLeftArrow] ParsedBoxWrapper[RowBox[{"MyPower", "[","A_", ",", "B_", "]"}]]]
```

It works fine with `MyPower[a,c]`, displaying `a^c`.
However if the case of `MyPower[a+b,c]`, the result is `a+b^c`.

The question is *how to make Mathematica to put parenthesis automatically, so I can get `a^c` in the first case and `(a+b)^c` in the second case*.

I believe that the answer is about setting the precedence order using `TagBox` function with `SyntaxForm` argument. However, this function is rather ill-documented and I couldn't get it work.

P.S.
I would like to note that automatic parenthesis placement works fine for binary operations:

```
Needs["Notation`"];
Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[RowBox[{"A_", " ", "plus"  , " ", "B_"}]] \[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow] ParsedBoxWrapper[RowBox[{"MyPlus", "[", RowBox[{"A_", ",", "B_"}], "]"}]]]
Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[RowBox[{"A_", " ", "times" , " ", "B_"}]] \[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow] ParsedBoxWrapper[RowBox[{"MyMult", "[", RowBox[{"A_", ",", "B_"}], "]"}]]]
MyPlus[a, MyMult[b, c]] (* Returns a plus (b times c) *)
MyMult[MyPlus[a, b], c] (* Returns (a plus b) times c *)

Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[RowBox[{"A_", " ", TagBox["plus", "", SyntaxForm -> "+"], " ", "B_"}]]\[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow]ParsedBoxWrapper[RowBox[{"MyPlus", "[", RowBox[{"A_", ",", "B_"}], "]"}]]]
Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[RowBox[{"A_", " ", TagBox["times", "", SyntaxForm -> "a"], " ", "B_"}]]\[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow]ParsedBoxWrapper[RowBox[{"MyMult", "[", RowBox[{"A_", ",", "B_"}], "]"}]]]
MyPlus[a, MyMult[b, c]] (* Returns a plus b times c *)
MyMult[MyPlus[a, b], c] (* Returns (a plus b) times c *)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your custom notation is identical to that of `Power`, I would do it the lazy way:

```
MakeBoxes[ myPower[base_, exp_], form_ ] :=
  TagBox[ MakeBoxes[ base^exp, form], myPower] ;

myPower @@@ {{x, y}, {x + y, z}, {x y, z}, {myPower[x, y], z}, {f[x, y], z}}
```

> { x<sup>y</sup>, (x+y)<sup>z</sup>, (x y)<sup>z</sup>, (x<sup>y</sup>)<sup>z</sup>, f[x, y]<sup>z</sup> }

```
% // InputForm
```

> {myPower[x, y], myPower[x + y, z], myPower[x*y, z], myPower[myPower[x, y], z], myPower[f[x, y], z]}

Answer (score 4):

Using

```
\((a + b ) \^ c \)
```

where `\^` is short form for `SuperscriptBox` within `\( ...\)`, gives

> SuperscriptBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"a", "+", "b"}], ")"}], "c"]

as pointed out by @jkuczm, you can then solve by using `RowBox`.

So I tried to do for the cases it didn't work and for others, like $(\frac{a}{b})^c$

I played a bit with the pattern matching in `Notation` but found it a bit confusing and inconsistent, maybe someone more familiar can do better. If you use the option `PrintNotationRules` you can see the function used to set the notation which is `NotationMakeBoxes`, here the pattern matching is more like what I am familiar with (not that I know much)

so using 2 separate cases:

```
NotationMakeBoxes[MyPower[A_?AtomQ, B_], StandardForm] := 
      SuperscriptBox[MakeBoxes[A, StandardForm], MakeBoxes[B, StandardForm]]

NotationMakeBoxes[MyPower[A_, B_], StandardForm] := 
      SuperscriptBox[RowBox[{"(", MakeBoxes[A, StandardForm], ")"}], 
      MakeBoxes[B, StandardForm]]
```

Using the examples in the other answer

```
MyPower[x, y]
```

> $x^y$

```
MyPower[x + y, z]
```

> $\left(x+y \right)^z$

```
MyPower[x y, z]
```

> $\left(x y \right)^z$

```
MyPower[x^y, z]
```

> $\left(x^y \right)^z$

```
MyPower[x, y^z]
```

> $ x^{y^{z}}$

```
MyPower[f[x, y], z]
```

> $(f[x,y])^z$

It wraps the last function in parentheses but that's because I only matched for Atoms, you can now modify to have all the patterns you want.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround you can wrap base of `MyPower` with additional `RowBox`:

```
Notation[
    ParsedBoxWrapper[SuperscriptBox[RowBox[{"A_", ""}],"B_"]]
    \[DoubleLongLeftArrow]
    ParsedBoxWrapper[RowBox[{"MyPower", "[", "A_", ",", "B_", "]"}]]
]
```

It works with `Plus`, `Times`, nested `MyPower` and custom functions:

```
MyPower[x, y]
MyPower[x + y, z]
MyPower[x y, z]
MyPower[MyPower2[x, y], z]
MyPower2[x, MyPower2[y, z]]
MyPower[f[x, y], z]
```

> x<sup>y</sup>
>
> (x + y)<sup>z</sup>
>
> (x y)<sup>z</sup>
>
> (x<sup>y</sup>)<sup>z</sup>
>
> x<sup>y<sup>z</sup></sup>
>
> f[x, y]<sup>y</sup>

Unfortunately it doesn't work as I would expect in combination with ordinary `Power`:

```
MyPower[x^y, z]
```

> x<sup>y z</sup>

Honestly, I don't know why it works as it does. I hope someone will give a better answer.

Comment: It doesn't work with noncommutative multiply: `MyPower[x ** y, z]`. The same problem with cross operator `MyPower[x\[Cross]y, z]`.