# Block Matrix Algebra of Implicit Matricies

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I get some unexpected behaviour from building block matrices of implicit matrices in Mathematica. Using this initial setup

```
$Assumptions = 
  A \[Element] Matrices[{3, 3}, Reals] &&  
   B \[Element] Matrices[{3, 3}, Reals] && 
   a \[Element] Vectors[3, Reals] && 
   b \[Element] Vectors[3, Reals] && \[Alpha] \[Element] 
    Reals &&  \[Beta] \[Element] Reals;
\[DoubleStruckCapitalA] = {{-\[Alpha], a\[Transpose]}, {a, A}};
\[DoubleStruckCapitalB] = {{-\[Beta], b\[Transpose]}, {b, B}};
```

**1)** For the product I get

```
{{\[Alpha] \[Beta] + b Transpose[a], 
  B Transpose[a] - \[Alpha] Transpose[b]}, {A b - a \[Beta], 
  A B + a Transpose[b]}}
```

But this is not correct, e.g. the top left should be αβ+Transpose[a].b. I've tried to exchange where I put the transpose, but with no difference. And b.Transpose[a] is not even a scalar! And Mathematica knows this from the fact that using TensorReduce returns "TensorDimenstions: Inhomogeneous dimensions in sum αβ+bTranspose[a]."

**2)** The transpose of the matrix is not correct:

```
Transpose[\[DoubleStruckCapitalA]]
```

Returns

```
{{-\[Alpha], a}, {Transpose[a], A}}
```

So it's missing the transpose of A.

I have plenty of more things that do not work, but I'd be happy if there is a way to get these examples to work.

I'm likely using this in the wrong way? If so, what is a good way to go?

Comment: In your definitions of AA and BB, try doing away with the `Transpose` altogether. Mathematica does not differentiate between row and column  vectors so you often don't need to either. Then the result would be `{{a b + α β, a B - b α}, {A b - a β, a b + A B}}`. Would that be more along the lines of what you seek?

Comment: Not really... Let say that I define a and b as {3,1} matrices instead. Then it does matter, but this sadly does not change what Mathematica does...

Comment: I don't think mixing explicit and symbolic matrices will work well. Mathematica works best when you stick to one or the other.

Comment: I guess one is restricted to writing something like this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37808/block-matrix-algebra-with-mathematica